# How to prevent importFrom statements from autodeletion from NAMESPACE file?

Tags: r, namespaces, package, devtools, roxygen2

My `NAMESPACE` file is:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.0.1): do not edit by hand
export(ARorderG)
export(VOBoegmc)
export(conddiffG)
................
export(sablon)
```

Upon trying to check the package via:

```
devtools::check("C:/Users/erdogan/Documents/Revolution/causfinder")
```

I received lots of errors like that:

```
conddiffG: *no visible global function definition for* 'b.star'.
```

**What I have already tried till now:** I added the following importfrom to `NAMESPACE file` *manually*:

```
importFrom(np, b.star)
```

I did these for *all* the "...no visible global function definition for..." errors. Then once more I triggered:

```
devtools::check("C:/Users/erdogan/Documents/Revolution/causfinder")
```

Unfortunately, *all* the importFrom statements were automatically deleted from `NAMESPACE` file. I read that this is due to re-creation of `NAMESPACE` file from `roxygen2`.

I needed importFrom statements for successful check of package to send CRAN, but `roxygen2` auto-deletes these importFrom statements and left only export statements.

How to prevent deletion of `importFrom` statements via using `roxygen2`?

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: What is `b.star`? Those errors generally mean you're trying to use an undeclared function somewhere in your package code. You want to remove those situations or handle imports/depends correctly in DESCRIPTION (or, I guess, in your Roxygen markup) rather than try to get around them in a hackish way.

Comment: @Thomas, b.star is a function that automatically finds optimal lengths in bootstrapping in tsboot. That's to say, b.star is a function in np. When my importFrom's are auto-deleted from NAMESPACE, I faced with "undeclared function somewhere in my package code" as you said. My DESCRIPTION file includes Imports: np(>= 0.50-1), and my un-auto-deleted NAMESPACE file includes importFrom(np,b.star). i.e. I am over-killing the prob. of facing an error, but do not understand why it remains. The Imports: np(>= 0.50-1) in DESC is not auto-deleted, and still undeclared func. error. Very interesting!

Comment: Are you putting the relevant `@importFrom np b.star` in your roxygen markup? Because then the importFrom line in `NAMESPACE` should be written automatically?

Comment: Thomas, I am not putting relevant @importFrom np b.star in my roxygen markup. I do not know to which file I must put it. What is the most proper place to put that mark up? In R working directory, package's R folder's help.R file?

Comment: It's part of your .R file where you write your roxygen markup (like where `@export` line is in [the roxygen2 README example](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/README.html)). Perhaps you need to review the basics of roxygen before you try to solve this specific issue.

Comment: Hımmm, I understand, you mean put "@importFrom np b.star" to the function of the package that used b.star. I will report you the result after I make all the relevant changes in R. files of the functions of the package. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`roxygen2` automatically updates the content of `NAMESPACE` file. Hence, in order to prevent `importFrom` statements in `NAMESPACE` file from auto-deletion, these statements must be brought to the `NAMESPACE` file from the `.R files` of the functions of the package; not to be written manually to `NAMESPACE` file. For the sake of arguement, let the function conddiffG use some function `b.star` of the package `np`. Then, in `conddiffG.R` of R folder of the package, we must write the following just before `#' @export` line:

```
#’ @importFrom np b.star
```

This will create `importFrom(np,b.star)` in `NAMESPACE` file automatically during the later processes (`roxygenize`, `build`, `install`, `library`, `devtools::check("C:/Users/erdogan/Documents/Revolution/thePacketContainingconddiffG")`...).

Comment: Depends.  Are you using RStudio? If so you can turn it off in "Project Options"

Comment: I installed R, RStudio, Revolution R to my PC. But I work with Revolution R and develop my functions and packages in Revolution R. Anyway, I will do what you say about RStudio: turning it off from Project Options.